# Не открывается модель на сайте Django

Tags: django

Прописала модель в Django, порписала внешний ключ, на сайте под админом модель появилось, но когда открываю ее, там ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама модель выглядит так:

```
class Article(models.Model):
article_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField()
pubmed = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='pubmed', blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateTimeField()
abstract = models.TextField()
fk_journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_journal')
keywords = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'article'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо ещё таблицу в БД создать. Запустите последовательно команды `python manage.py makemigrations` и `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: В БД таблица уже создана. Миграцию сделала. Всё равно не помогает(

Comment: Сообщение "relation 'article' does not exist" означает, что таблицы в БД нет. Возможно потому, что ложное значение атрибута `Meta.managed` исключает применение миграций.

Comment: может быть такое, что из-за того, что таблица находистся в другой схеме, он ее не видит?

Comment: Попробуйте в [OPTIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-OPTIONS) добавить `'options': '-c search_path=public,your_scheme'`

Comment: почему-то тоже не помогает.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! но в одной из модели при открытии данных возникает такая ошибка: AttributeError at /admin/cannabis/article/77/change/
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'